# Is $a^b$ transcendental when $a$ and $b$ are?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

I am being asked this question as an exercise in Garling's "A course in Galois theory". But isn't this an open question in math?

Comment: Like $e^{i\pi}$?

Comment: No: $e$ and $\log2$ are transcendental, but $2$ is not.

Comment: @Andres: That should be an answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Go ahead.

Comment: Yeah. That's indeed an easy counterexample. Are there others which are not of the form $re^{iaπ}$. With others I mean simple ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  We know $e$ and $\log(2)$ are transcendental, but $$e^{\log 2}=2.$$

Comment: Why is it that I feel I am being tricked ? :)

Comment: I know what you mean. I had a similar reaction when I learned that [every value of $i^i$ is *real*](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/191578/28900).