# Calculate $i ^ {i+1}$ and also $i^{i^{i^{\dots}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I just wanted to ask the following questions please. 
The first I have is calculate $i^{(i+1)}$ and also $i^i$ 
I was just wondering if anyone can nudge me in the right direction to solve these questions.

many thanks!

Comment: $a^b = e^{b\log a}.$

Comment: I'm also interested in seeing how this is done. I guess all comes to the definition but I have been searching for it for so long. Can someone or at least give some reference to the theory which defines complex exponentiation? Pls :)

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/prove-that-ii-is-a-real-number

Comment: It's not that easy with complex numbers, @user7530 ...

Comment: Have you already studied the complex logarithm, @Mathsider?

Comment: It is a nice idea to compute I^I^I^I...For I^I, we get the know result Exp[- Pi /2]. For I^I^I, the result is quite nice and simple. Increasing the power tower, the expressions are very esthetical (at least for me).

Comment: @DonAntonio Sure, but it's also not so difficult; write $b = re^{i\theta}$, use the product law for $\log$, and notice there is a periodic set of solutions.

Comment: Also, from $e^{i\pi} = -1$ you can derive $i^i$.

Comment: The product law for exponents/logarithms does **not** work with complex numbers: one *must* choose a branch cut for the complex logarithm, an infinitely-valued function.

Answer (score 4):

Choosing the usual branch for the complex logarithm, we get

$$i^i=e^{i\,\text{Log}\,i}=e^{i\left(\log 1+i\arg i\right)}=e^{i\cdot\frac{\pi i}2}=e^{-\frac\pi2}$$

Thus

$$i^{i+1}=ii^i=e^{-\frac\pi2}\cdot i$$

Comment: Do all these things come from complex analysis?

Comment: Yup, @Inwvr ...

Comment: Thank you! This is great! Forgot about that pesky property! :P

Answer (score 0):

$i^{i+1}=\{e^{i\pi/2}\}^{i+1}=e^{(i+1)i\pi/2}=e^{i\pi/2-\pi/2}=ie^{-\pi/2}$

Here, we made use of the identity, $e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$.

For the second quantity (post-edit, different from question in title?), just divide the previous by $i$.

Comment: You should check your message before you post it, @dan

Answer (score 0):

One may also view $i^i$ as the set $\{e^{-\pi(2k+1)}\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.