# What is $i^i$ and $(i^i)^i$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

What is $i^i$ and $(i^i)^i$. I fond some answers [online](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20013.3.shtml) but is there a clearer explanation of this? Maybe something help me to understand.

Comment: You are not familiar with Euler's identity?

Comment: No, could you recommend me some text for this? Thanks.

Comment: Using the representation that $i = e^{i \pi/2}$, we have $i^i = \left(e^{i\pi/2}\right)^i = e^{i^2\pi/2} = e^{-\pi/2}$. Your problem seems to be answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/prove-that-ii-is-a-real-number)

Comment: For complex numbers $z$, we define $a^z := \exp (z \log a)$, but in general this depends on a choice of branch cut of the logarithm function.

Comment: This has already been discussed to death several times on the site...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, complex power of $a^b$ $(a\ne 0)$ is defined as
$$
a^b = e^{b\log a}.
$$
Thus
$$
i^i = e^{i\log i}=e^{i(\operatorname{Ln}1+i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi))}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} -2k\pi}
$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and
$$
(i^i)^i =\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} -2k\pi}\right)^i=e^{i\log\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} -2k\pi}\right)}=e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{2}-2k\pi+i2k'\pi)}=-ie^{-2k'\pi}
$$
for $k'\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

These are both multiple-valued expressions. Generally one computes $w^z$ as $e^{z\log w}$, so the multiple-valuedness comes from that of the logarithm.

First, since the values of $\log i$ are $\frac{\pi i}{2} -2k\pi i$, the values of $i^i$ are
$$z_k=e^{i(\frac{\pi i}{2} -2k\pi i)}=\boxed{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}(4k-1)}}
$$
for integral $k$.

Then, since the values of $\log z_k$ are $\frac{\pi}{2}(4k-1) - 2n\pi i=2\pi k -\frac{\pi}{2}-2n\pi i$, the values of each $z_k^i$ are
$$z_{k,n}=e^{i(2\pi k -\frac{\pi}{2}-2n\pi i)} =e^{2n\pi}\cdot e^{2k\pi i -\frac{\pi i}{2}  } = -ie^{2n\pi}
$$ for integral $n$ and $k$. As it happens, for a given $n$, the values of $z_{n,k}$ coincide for each integral $k$, so we may suppress the unneeded subscript. Then we have the possible values of $(i^i)^i$ are
$$\hat{z}_{k} = \boxed{-ie^{2k\pi}}$$
for integral $k$.

Note that the previous answers are incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

Start by representing $i$ in exponential form via the Euler relation:
$$i = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
Then combine exponents to get the answer:
$$i^i = e^{i * i\frac{\pi}{2}} = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
To get to your second term, combine exponents and then take advantage of the fact that powers of $i$ form a group with integer exponents modulo 4:
$$(i^i)^i = (e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}})^i = e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}} = i^{-1} = i^{4-1} = i^3 = -i$$
I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not correct, because $z^{\alpha\beta}=(z^{\alpha})^{\beta}$ does not hold, in general.

Comment: @choco_addicted: More properly, these are both incomplete. The state values are indeed valid values of these expressions, but there are infinitely many distinct values of both.