# Fiding imaginary part of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> What is the imaginary part of $i^i$ ?

I've tried multiple approaches, including using log. I can't seem to understand how to work with complex numbers as logarithmic functions.
Also, it would help if someone could explain what the value of $\log{(-i)}$ is?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is i^i already?

Comment: Try using Euler's formula.

Comment: $i^i$ is multivalued, and always real. The imaginary part is zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $i^i$ is a real number](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/prove-that-ii-is-a-real-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $i^i=e^{i\log i}$ for some suitable value of $\log i$. One fine choice is $\log i = \frac{\pi i}{2}$. In that case, we obtain:

$i^i = e^{i\cdot\frac{\pi i}{2}} = e^{-\pi/2}$,

which is a real number with imaginary part $0$. Indeed, any choice for $\log i$ is going to be a purely imaginary number, so when you multiply it by $i$, you'll get a purely real number.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

$i^i$ is real and $=e^{-\pi/2} \approx0.2078795\dots$ thus its imaginary part is $0$.

I believe a similar [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/prove-that-ii-is-a-real-number) about the value of $i^i$ was asked before, so you can see that for more information.

You can also see simple [Mathematical Proof Using the Euler’s Formula](http://proofsfromthebook.com/2013/09/14/proof-ii-real-number/).