# Imaginary raised to imaginary?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

How do you show that

$i^i = -i^{-i} =  0.207879576350761908546955619834978770033877841631769608075...$

likewise for

$-i^i = i^{-i} = 4.810477380965351655473035666703833126390170874664534940020...$

?

Comment: I think it's more complicated, have a look on this topics :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/prove-that-ii-is-a-real-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^y = \exp(y \log(x))$$

so you want $$\exp(i \log(i)) = \exp\left(i \times \frac{i \pi}{2}\right) = \exp(-\pi/2)$$

The others are similar.