# Complex Logarithms and Powers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, complex-integration

Express each of the following complex numbers in Cartesian form (that is, in the form a+ib for a,b∈R), where Log denotes the Principal Complex Logarithm and the powers are Principal Complex Powers::

a) $$(ie)^{(i\pi)}$$

Note ($i\pi$) is the power for ($ie$) in this case sorry a bit new to this platform.

So I know this go down to like
$$\exp(i\pi(\log(ie))$$

a bit confused on how to progress forward.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thankyou buddy I shall check it out :)

Comment: Alright ok I shall try that out

Comment: done thankyou hope this is slightly better now

Comment: When you have an exponent with more than one character, you have to put it in braces.  So, `$e^\pi$` gives $e^\pi$, but for $e^{i\pi}$ we need `$e^{i\pi}$`.

Comment: Thankyou I think someone helped me out with that.

Comment: Would anyone mind solving this ?

Comment: Have you looked at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/understanding-imaginary-exponents and this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/prove-that-ii-is-a-real-number

Comment: yes i have but this is much more different than that

Comment: What is the formula for $\log z$?

Comment: log(|z|)+iArg(z)

Comment: Using that formula, what is $\log(ie)$?