# Complex power of a complex number: Find $x$ and $y$ in $x + yi = (a + bi)^{c+di}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

$$
x + yi = (a + bi)^{c+di}
$$

Find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.
Where,  $i$ is defined as $\sqrt{-1}$ and  $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are real numbers.

---

I defined two new real number variables

$$
r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \\
\theta = arg(a + bi).
$$

The expression becomes

$$
x + yi = \left(re^{\theta i}\right)^{c+di} = r^{c+di}e^{-\theta d + \theta c i} = \left[r^{c}e^{-\theta d}\right]r^{di}e^{\theta c i} = \left[r^{c}e^{-\theta d}\right]r^{di}(cos(\theta c) + isin(\theta c)) \\
= r^{di}\left[r^{c}e^{-\theta d}cos(\theta c) + ir^{c}e^{-\theta d}sin(\theta c)\right].
$$

I'm not able to go on any further because of the term $r^{di}$. I don't know how to open it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189703/does-ii-and-i1-over-e-have-more-than-one-root-in-0-2-pi/191966#191966

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201991/for-what-values-alpha-for-complex-z-lnz-alpha-alpha-lnz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
&& x + jy = (a + jb)^{c+jd} \\
&=& (re^{j\theta})^{c+jd} \\
&=& r^{c+jd} (e^{j\theta})^{c+jd} \\
&=& r^cr^{jd} e^{j\theta c}e^{-\theta d} \\
&=& r^c e^{\displaystyle\ln r^{jd}} e^{j\theta c}e^{-\theta d} \\
&=& r^c e^{-\theta d} e^{\displaystyle jd \ln r} e^{\displaystyle j\theta c} \\
&=& r^c e^{-\theta d} e^{\displaystyle j(d \ln r + \theta c)} \\
&=& r^c e^{-\theta d} [\cos(d \ln r + \theta c) + j\sin(d \ln r + \theta c)] \\
&=& [r^c e^{-\theta d} \cos(d \ln r + \theta c)] + j[r^c e^{-\theta d}\sin(d \ln r + \theta c)] \\
&=& \left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-\theta d} \cos\left(d \ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}) + \theta c\right)\right] + \\
&&  \left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-\theta d}\sin\left(d \ln((a^2+b^2)^{1/2}) + \theta c\right)\right]j \\
&=& \left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-\theta d} \cos\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + \theta c\right)\right] + \\
&&  \left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-\theta d}\sin\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + \theta c\right)\right]j \\
&=& \begin{cases}
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-d\arctan(\frac{b}{a})} \cos\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + c\,\arctan(\frac{b}{a})\right)\right] + &\\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-d\arctan(\frac{b}{a})} \sin\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + c\,\arctan(\frac{b}{a})\right)\right]j &  \text{if} \; a\!>\!0 \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-d\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) - \pi d} \cos\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + c\,\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) + \pi c\right)\right] + & \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-d\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) - \pi d} \sin\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + c\,\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) + \pi c\right)\right]j &  \text{if} \; a\!<\!0 \; \text{and} \; b \!\ge\! 0 \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-d\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) + \pi d} \cos\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + c\,\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) - \pi c\right)\right] + & \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-d\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) + \pi d} \sin\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + c\,\arctan(\frac{b}{a}) - \pi c\right)\right]j &  \text{if} \; a\!<\!0 \; \text{and} \; b\!<\!0 \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-\frac{\pi d}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + \frac{\pi c}{2}\right)\right] + & \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{-\frac{\pi d}{2}} \sin\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) + \frac{\pi c}{2}\right)\right]j &  \text{if} \; a\!=\!0 \; \text{and} \; b\!>\!0 \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{+\frac{\pi d}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) - \frac{\pi c}{2}\right)\right] + & \\
\left[(a^2+b^2)^{c/2} e^{+\frac{\pi d}{2}} \sin\left(\frac{d}{2} \ln(a^2+b^2) - \frac{\pi c}{2}\right)\right]j &  \text{if} \; a\!=\!0 \; \text{and} \; b\!<\!0 \\
0 &  \text{if} \; a\!=\!0 \; \text{and} \; b\!=\!0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{array}
$$

---

Implementation in computer:

```
ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::TakePower(const ComplexNumber & Base, const ComplexNumber & Exponent)
{
    // x + jy = (a + jb)^(c + jd)
    double x, y;
    double a = Base.GetRealPart();
    double b = Base.GetImaginaryPart();
    if (IsZero(a) & IsZero(b))
    {
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        double c = Exponent.GetRealPart();
        double d = Exponent.GetImaginaryPart();
        double r2 = a * a + b * b;
        double t = Base.GetAngle();
        x = pow(r2, c/2.0) * exp(-t*d) * cos((d/2.0) * log(r2) + t*c);
        y = pow(r2, c/2.0) * exp(-t*d) * sin((d/2.0) * log(r2) + t*c);  
    }
    return ComplexNumber(x, y);
}
```

Testing for $e^{j\pi}\!=\!-1$:

```
double e = 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995;
double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
ComplexNumber cne(e, 0);
ComplexNumber cni(0, pi);
ComplexNumber cnei = cne.GetPower(cni);
std::cout << "e^(j*pi) = " << cnei.ToString() << std::endl;
```

Program output:

> e^(j*pi) = -1+j1.22465e-016

My implementation calculates $e^{j\pi}$ as $-1\!+\!j1.22465\!\times\!10^{-16}$. I don't know the reason for the error in the imaginary part, but the result is still very close enough to the actual one.

Comment: The steps may be shortened by taking logarithm in both sides in the first step and knowing that $\ln{z}=\ln{|z|}+i\arg{z}$ (Principal value)

Answer (score 1):

For $\,r,d\in\Bbb R\,$ :

$$r^{di}=e^{di\,\text{Log}(r)}=e^{ri\left(\log|r|+i\arg(r)\right)}$$

Choosing the usual branch for the complex logarithm Log$(z)$ where positive reals have argument equal to zero gives you a result pretty similar to the one would expect from real analysis...

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use Euler's equation. $$ e^{(i\theta)} =cos(\theta)+i sin(\theta)$$ 
Extending to a general base is messy, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. You can continue like this:

$$(a+ib)^{c+di} = \ldots ... = r^ce^{-d\theta}e^{i(c\theta+d\ln r)}=\\
= r^ce^{-d\theta}\cos(c\theta+d\ln r) + ir^ce^{-d\theta}\sin(c\theta+d\ln r)$$