# Find all the values of $(1+i)^{(1-i)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The question says to find all the values of $(1+i)^{(1-i)}$

I have trouble figuring out firstly, exactly what values are being looked for. I can toy around with the equation a bit to try to make it look "acceptable" (i.e $ax + byi$ format) but get stuck along the way. So I need help with:

a) figuring out what values are needed. i.e. what does the question $mean$ and some brief background or diagram that explains, in a practical sense, what I'm supposed to be looking for.

b) the algebra that can lead me to a reasonable solution.

--

MY ATTEMPT:

$$ (1+i)^{(1-i)} = (1+i)^{(1-i)}.\frac{(1+i)^{(1+i)}}{(1+i)^{(1+i)}} = \frac{(1+i)^2}{(1+i)^{(1+i)}} = *$$

*is where I get stuck.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189703/does-ii-and-i1-over-e-have-more-than-one-root-in-0-2-pi

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you! It was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

In general, $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$. Now in complex analysis, the logarithm function can be considered multi-valued, so if $A$ is one possible value for $\ln a$, the other possibilities are $A+2\pi i n$ with an integer $n$. Now substitute that into your formula.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip! Using it I ended up with the following answer: $$ 2(1+i) e^{(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k \pi)+(\frac{\pi}{4} - 2k{\pi})i}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$,
\begin{align*}
  e^{2n\pi i} &= 1 \\
  1+i &=
  \exp \left[ \frac{\ln 2}{2}+i\pi \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \right] \\
  (1+i)^{1-i} &=
  \exp \left[
         \frac{1-i}{2} \ln 2+i(1-i) \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi
       \right] \\
  &= 
  \exp \left[
          \frac{\ln 2}{2}+\left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi+
         i\left( -\frac{\ln 2}{2}+2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)
       \right] \\
  &= \sqrt{2} \, \exp \left[
                         \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi+
                        i\left( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2} \right)
                      \right] \\
  &= \sqrt{2} \, e^{\left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi}
     \left[
        \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2} \right)+
       i\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2} \right)
     \right]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Continue developing the exponential using Moivre formula and expand again to isolate the real and imaginary parts. You will end with a nice formula in the form of (a + I b). Are you able to continue with this ?