# Find all values of $(1+i)^{1+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$z=(1+i)^{1+i}$$

I'm having trouble with this one. I got as far as the below, but then I got stuck. Could someone give me a hint??

$$\ln(z)=(1+i)\ln(1+i)$$

---

After reading the hints + suggested answer:

$$z=(1+i)^{1+i}$$
$$z=e^{(1+i)ln(1+i)}$$
$$z=e^{(1+i)ln|1+i|+(arg(1+i)+2\pi k)i}$$
$$z=e^{ln(\sqrt{2})+\pi i/4+2\pi ik+iln(\sqrt{2})-\pi /4-2\pi k}$$

Is it ok to leave my final answer like this?

Comment: Write $(1+i)$ in the form $re^{i\theta}$

Comment: Find an answer in [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540230/find-all-the-values-of-1i1-i), which is very similar.

Comment: @George I tried it your way: $z=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi /4}ln(\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi /4})=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi /4}(ln|\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi /4}|+(arg(\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi /4})+2\pi k)i)$. Now it seems as though the key here would be to recognize that the modulus of a complex number in polar form is easily seen in the first number of the term, e.g. the $\sqrt{2}$. Same thing for the argument, it is the $\pi /4$. Thus $z=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi /4}(ln(\sqrt{2})+(\pi /4 +2\pi k)i)$. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

$\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$,
\begin{align*}
  e^{2n\pi i} &= 1 \\
  1+i &=
  \exp \left[ \frac{\ln 2}{2}+i\pi \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \right] \\
  (1+i)^{1+i} &=
  \exp \left[
         \frac{1+i}{2} \ln 2+i(1+i) \left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi
       \right] \\
  &= 
  \exp \left[
          \frac{\ln 2}{2}-\left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi+
         i\left( \frac{\ln 2}{2}+2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)
       \right] \\
  &= \sqrt{2} \, \exp \left[
                        -\left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi+
                        i\left( \frac{\ln 2}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)
                      \right] \\
  &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{e^{\left( 2n+\frac{1}{4} \right) \pi}}
     \left[
        \cos \left( \frac{\ln 2}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)+
       i\sin \left( \frac{\ln 2}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)
     \right]
\end{align*}